# Ubuntu 10.10 - disaster - what other linux for beginner?

Tags: linux

Guys, I've tried to install ubuntu (desktop and notebook ed) on my laptop and unortunately I have to say that as despite the fact that installation process supposed to be easy I couldn't finish installation of this system - didn't detect my keyboard or rather lost my keyboard as soon as I tried to switch on/off pad on my laptop. After I've discovered that, I started all over again (this time without touching my laptop's pad during installation) and yes, eventually it get to the end of installation.

Unfortunately, when I've tried to switch my pad (sometimes I just do not want to use a mouse) the whole system froze. So I had to restart it with the power button and this time I didn't touch pad at all, plugged in mouse and tried to rearrange taskbars according to my liking (all taskbars on the top side of the screen and auto-hide on) and I gave up.  It is so unfinished that I just can't be bothered to use it.

I would like to have one linux system on my machine so I started googling and most of the links are to either ubuntu (which I just do not want to touch for now) and suse or commercial versions of linux. I do not really mind paying for something (and having experience with ubuntu I'd rather pay and have something pro then get it free and discover that it's unusable).

So could someone please provide short list of linux distros which would be appropriate for a beginner, and I don't mind paying for it, I just want it to be a professional product.

Comment: If you downvote at least have the decency and say why did you do that.

Comment: ...or just look at your own long question, and its lack of formatting, and wonder if anything could be improved?

Comment: Hi try posting this to unix.SE or askubuntu.com

Comment: probably because you gave a lot of rambling and unnecessary context. if your question is 'what distro should i use', then that is a common question on superuser.com -- try searching. if your question is about how to install ubuntu, try askubuntu.com.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but the question is poorly written. You've insulted 50% of the population (okay, this is a computer site, so probably less than 50% of the users) with your comment "as easy as women". You've called a distro unfinished because you couldn't figure out how to do a task, you've went out of your way to get rid of the newline between paragraphs which makes it much harder to read.

Comment: Ubuntu is being maintained by a professional company called canonical, Ubuntu is never a finished product and improvement could always be made. (But hey, it's not like Windows is perfect!) You can't expect them to support every bit of hardware that is out there and moreover, I think you should consider that most hardware is designed to work with Windows... I think I'm safe to say that Ubuntu will run pretty darn well on the majority  of all generic computers in use. I think that's pretty good for a free product... (Which is by the way, not an amateur product IMHO)

Comment: @Macha I didn't called distro unfinished because I couldn't figure out how to do a task. I called it unfinished because it couldn't recognize very popular brand of hardware.

Comment: BloodPhilia I do not expect them to support every hardware but the most popular yes. And what do you mean by not an amateur product?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your problem is only that pad doesn't work?

Well, it likely means that the module (ie: driver) Ubuntu ships for your pad is broken. I'd suggest you to investigate a little more: what pad have you got? You should submit a bug report to Ubuntu bugzilla.

It's possible that other distributions ship the same broken module (or whatever it is), and you'll encounter the same bug wherever.

Anyway, if you're decided to try other distributions, the most easy to use are, in my opinion:

- Ubuntu
- Fedora
- Suse
- Madriva